# How to deal with purgeIdleCellConnections on 3G network?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, 3g

I added thirdparty SDK to my project, and I got purgeIdleCellConnections errors when using slow 3G network .

```
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1f55b300
```

There is no problem on wifi network , because it don't use the cellular network for the image downloads.

I have to determine if network type is wifi or 3G :

```
+ (BOOL) IsEnableWIFI {
    return ([[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi]
             currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable);
}

+ (BOOL) IsEnable3G {
    return ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]
             currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable);
}
```

But I think this is not a good idea. How to deal with it ?

Thank you for any replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have observed this debug message coming out of the iOS 6.0 SDK (when on the device connected to cellular network), correlates to active AJAX calls being terminated in my app.  However it is very difficult to prove anything since this only occurs when rendering the web page in a UIWebView.  I am just saying I don't think the messages are benign.  I think they might indicate a bug in the Apple framework that is overly aggressive in terminating connections.  It is hard to get instrumentation on the javascript running inside the UIWebView that makes the AJAX calls, so it is all highly speculative at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a debug log which came in IOS6 SDK, don't worry about this.